# SQL QUERY FROM 25(LAST MONTH) to 25(CURRENT MONTH)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like a query that would include from day 25 of last month to 25 of current month. Example: 25/12/2017-25/01/2018

I can't do something like transaction_date >= getdate()-31 because there are months that have 28,29 days.

Thanks!

Comment: Which version of SQL Server you are using?

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
SELECT *
FROM your_tab
WHERE transaction_date 
BETWEEN DATEFROMPARTS(IIF(MONTH(GETDATE()) = 1,YEAR(GETDATE())-1,YEAR(GETDATE())),
                      IIF(MONTH(GETDATE()) = 1, 12 , MONTH(GETDATE())-1)
                      ,25) 
          AND DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), MONTH(GETDATE()), 25);
```

Comment: `IIF` available only from SQL Server 2012

Comment: @Sankar Easy to replace with CASE, but thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 2):

One easy way

```
where 
    transaction_date between dateadd(dd, 25, eomonth(getdate(),-2)) 
    and dateadd(dd, 25, eomonth(getdate(),-1))
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest `DATEFROMPARTS` to make a date with a set day, and subtract 1 month from the beginning:

`WHERE [transaction_date] BETWEEN DATEADD(month, -1, DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), MONTH(GETDATE()), 25)) AND DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), MONTH(GETDATE()), 25)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use datetime functions to substract a month from a date:

```
-- Feb 2016 is 29 days
select dateadd(month, -1, '2016-01-25 00:00')
>> 2015-12-25 00:00:00.000
select dateadd(month, -1, '2016-02-25 00:00')
>> 2016-01-25 00:00:00.000
select dateadd(month, -1, '2016-03-25 00:00')
>> 2016-02-25 00:00:00.000

-- Feb 2017 is 28 days
select dateadd(month, -1, '2017-01-25 00:00')
>> 2016-12-25 00:00:00.000
select dateadd(month, -1, '2017-02-25 00:00')
>> 2017-01-25 00:00:00.000
select dateadd(month, -1, '2017-03-25 00:00')
>> 2017-02-25 00:00:00.000


declare @thatDate datetime = '2017-01-25 00:00'

select *
from ThisTable
where ThisDate between dateadd(month, -1, @thatDate) and @thatDate
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on mysql this might work:

```
SELECT * 
FROM SOME_TABLE
WHERE transaction_date 
BETWEEN 
    DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-25') - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
AND 
    DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-25')
```

Answer (score -1):

You could do something along the lines of:

```
    Select fields from table
    where whateverDate > '25/12/2017' and
    whateverDate < '25/01/2018'
```